# What year is Akatsuki No Yona set in?

Tags: yona-of-the-dawn

I'm kind of confused about what year *Akatsuki no Yona* is set in. In the manga, Zeno claims to be more than 2000 years old.

So, shouldn't it be Year 2000 or something around that? Even though it looks like it's been set way, way, WAY before that.

Comment: Umm... Even if the calendar says its year 2017, doesn't mean the human civilization is only 2000 years old. Its an arbitary number that has been picked where a certain point in time is called 0. For Example, in movie 2012, after the "apocalypse" ends and the humans emerge from the ships, the Year is redubbed as Year 1.

Comment: Ooohhh, i get it now but i feel dumb lol, thanks!

Comment: The series might not even be in the same world as ours. We don't have magic...

Answer (score 3):

The answer can be found from here, [Why do the characters in Akatsuki no Yona have Korean names?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/why-do-the-characters-in-akatsuki-no-yona-have-korean-names).

> The setting for Akatsuki no Yona is loosely based on the [Three Kingdoms of Korea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms_of_Korea) period. The [Kouka Kingdom](http://akatsukinoyona.wikia.com/wiki/Kouka_Kingdom) is inspired by the Goguryeo Kingdom. Its neighbor Sei and Xing are based on Baekje and Silla respectively. You can also see that the three kingdoms are located in a peninsula in the manga and that they almost have the same layout as their real-life counterparts.

From the Wikipedia article,

> The concept of the Three Kingdoms of Korea (Hangul: 삼국시대; Hanja: 三國時代) refers to the three kingdoms of Baekje (百濟), Silla (新羅) and Goguryeo (高句麗), which was later known as Goryeo (高麗), from which the name Korea is derived. **The Three Kingdoms period was defined as being from 57 BC to 668 AD**

Thus, it is safe to say from the setting and inspiration that *Akatsuki no Yona*, may be from a similar time period, where obviously dragons exist.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Arcane's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/38227/2516).

The story is based off Korean culture and the Three Kingdoms Dynasty. The clothing is also Goryeo clothing. Examples of real life, you can compare to the character's clothing:

- Male:

  [image]

  <sup>From a K-drama *Moon Lovers: Scarlet Heart Ryeo*. https://kpop.asiachan.com/full/74097.</sup>
- Female:

  [image]

  <sup>Hae Soo wearing *hanbok*, from a K-drama *Moon Lovers: Scarlet Heart Ryeo*. https://aminoapps.com/c/korean-fashion/page/blog/hanbok-hae-soo-in-scarlet-heart-ryeo/z6og_2Vauxu0zQdLwWwb0YNVRGRYME2PYNkcn.</sup>

The clothing, names, and mapping is similar to Korean. Kinda seems like an anime K-drama to me.

You can also try looking up 'scarlet heart ryeo clothing'. You can see the clothing design is exactly the same as the characters from the Kyouka empire.

Answer (score -1):

*Yona of the Dawn* is based on Chinese culture, Chinese hanfu, Chinese Manchu clothes, Chinese architecture, and Chinese landscapes. The background is a fictional Chinese-style country. It uses a lot of Chinese elements. The ED song uses Chinese instruments and lyrics.

Don't use *Scarlet Heart Ryeo* as evidence. *Scarlet Heart Ryeo* is invested by China. The investor said this TV drama promotes Chinese culture, not Korean culture. All the clothes in *Scarlet Heart Ryeo* are Chinese hanfu, not hanbok. China has a lot of cultural relics to prove that.

Comment: Hi, please note that the question asks about the year the series is set in. While mentioning what the series is based on might help, it is still unclear what years specifically they were from. Consider [edit]ing and clarifying the post to answer the question asked. Thanks.